# Generate Microsoft CRM 4 report on schedule for each client

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-4

We have an "Client" entity and each client entity contains multiple invoices, now we need an automated process which runs automatically each night to generate a PDF report of all invoices belongs to that client and send it to client email address. The process should run for all clients mean we have to send the multiple emails.

We need an advise how we can do this job.

NOTE: we are using Microsoft CRM 4.0

Answer (score 0):

So this should be relatively straightforward, though it is a little involved.

1. Create an SSRS report which for a given Client presents the information you require.
2. Write some code that finds every Client and programmatically generate the SSRS report as shown [here](http://36chambers.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/reporting-services-2008-creating-reports-programmatically-without-using-a-reportviewer/).
3. Create an email record in Crm programmatically and attach the generated report.
4. Run this code in some scheduled process such as a windows service or workflow.